# AVAudioSessionMediaServicesWereResetNotification equivalent in iOS 5?

Tags: ios, avaudiosession, audiosession

The AVAudioSessionMediaServicesWereResetNotification was introduced in iOS 6. I need the same event in previous iOS versions.

I searched the Apple documentation without any luck.

In iOS 5 I tried listening with AudioSessionAddPropertyListener for the property kAudioSessionProperty_ServerDied but is not being called in the same scenario that is called AVAudioSessionMediaServicesWereResetNotification in iOS 6+.

Comment: which scenario is used for AVAudioSessionMediaServicesWereResetNotification in iOS 6+ ?